# Is there a way to pass 'self' or 'this' when calling a function inline in Flex for current component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I hope I have worded the question ok.

I know that you can pass the 'id' of the component but I'm just wondering if there is a more generic way.  I have tried using 'this' (shown in example below) but the 'this' keyword refers to the application.

Example:

```
<mx:Button click="someFunc(this)"/>
```

And the following function call doesn't work (as it's the wrong type):

```
someFunc(comp : UIComponent) : void {
    comp.label = 'Change label';
}
```

If I have 20 components I'd like to be able to call the same function without using 'id' for the different components.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the 'this' keyword refers to the application.

In an MXML component, The this" keyword will refer to the "top level" tag; which will not be the application in many situations.

In your case, I would pass in the click event and use the target or currentTarget properties to figure out which component was clicked:

```
<mx:Button click="someFunc(event)"/>

someFunc(event:MouseEvent) : void {
    trace(event.target);
    trace(event.currentTarget);
    (event.target as Button).label = "Change Label";
}
```

I'm pretty sure that you'll need target; as that will always be the component that dispatched the event.

Comment: The `target` is in no way guaranteed to be the Button, and if `mouseChildren` is enabled, it most likely won't be.  `currentTarget` however, is guaranteed to be the component which the listener is attached to.

Comment: The button component was only really used as an example.  It was more for any component that I wanted to use 'this' or 'self'.  I always forget about the target and currentTarget variables in an event handler...  I think this is the closest there is to 'this' or 'self' in Flex.  Just a side note... I'm always confused of when to use event.target or event.currentTarget!

Thanks for the answer @www.Flextras.com